# Update State component after fetch Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

First, sorry for my english :)

I'm learning React and Redux. I just want to know why I can't update the state of one container with redux. The only way to fix this probleme is to write a set Time out function (because JS is asynchronous). 
But I'm sure, that there is a better way to code what I want to do. If someone could help me please. 
My fetch is running without any probleme.

Container FormAmdmin.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import {getFormAdmin} from '../Actions/PostFormAdmin';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './FormAdmin.css'


const MapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({getFormAdmin}, dispatch)
}

const MapStateToProps = state => {
    return {Auth : state.Auth}
}

class FormAdmin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            isSuccess: false,
            response : {}
        };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log(nextProps)
        let response = nextProps.Auth.response
        let isSuccess = nextProps.Auth.isSuccess
        this.setState({
            response,
            isSuccess
        })
        this.onNaviguateAdmin()
   }

    // there 's no change to the state of my component
       onNaviguateAdmin = () => {
       console.log(this.state)
    }

    // It's working thanks to a setTimeOut Fonction
    //    onNaviguateAdmin = () => {
    //     setTimeout(() => {
    //         console.log('succes', this.state)
    //     }, 1000)

    // }


    handleChange(e){
       this.setState({
           [e.target.name] : e.target.value
       })
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        const body = {
            email : this.state.email,
            password : this.state.password
        }
       this.props.getFormAdmin(body)
     }

    render() {
    console.log('state render', this.state) // The state in the render is OK
     const { Auth } = this.props
     let divResult = <div></div>
       if (this.state.response.flash ==='ok') {
        divResult = <div>Connexion réussie</div>
       }
       else if (this.state.response.flash ==='Not a yet a Success') {
           divResult = <div>Identifiants ou mot de passe invalides</div>
       }

        return (
            <div className="ContainerFormAdmin">
                <Container fluid>
                    <h3>Administration du site</h3>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={12}>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <h5>Connexion à l\'Administration</h5>
                            <div>
                            <TextField 

                            name="email"
                            id="email"
                            label="email"
                            margin="normal"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                            </div>
                           <div>
                           <TextField 

                           name ="password"
                           id="password"
                           label="password"
                           margin="normal"
                           onChange={this.handleChange}
                           />
                           </div> 
                           <Button
                           type="submit"
                           >Connexion</Button>

                        </form>

                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
                <div>{divResult}</div>

        </div>

        );
    }
}


export default connect(MapStateToProps, MapDispatchToProps)(FormAdmin);
```

I use MapDispatchToProps to get an action : the fetch. I would like to get the response in the state of my component. That's why I'm using "componentWillReceiveProps" to update my state. But It's not working.

AuthReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    error: null,
    response: {},
    isSuccess: false
}

const FormAdmin = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log('je rentre dans auth reducers')
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FORM_ADMIN_SUCCESS':
            if (action.payload.json.flash === 'ok') {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    response: action.payload.json,
                    isSuccess: true
                }
            } else if
                (action.payload.json.flash === 'Not a yet a Success'){
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        response: action.payload.json,
                        isSuccess: false
                    }
                }
        break   
        case 'FORM_ADMIN_ERROR':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: true,
                isSuccess: false
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default FormAdmin
```

Action PostFormAdmin.js

```
export const postFormAdminSuccess = (json) => ({
    type : 'FORM_ADMIN_SUCCESS', 
    payload : {json}
})

export const postFormAdminError = (error) => ({
    type : 'FORM_ADMIN_ERROR', 
    payload : {error}
})



function handleError(response){

    if (!response.ok){
        throw Error(response.statusText)
    }
   return response
}


export function getFormAdmin(formAdmin){
   return(dispatch) => {
        return fetch('http://localhost:4000/admin', {
            method : 'POST', 
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
            body : JSON.stringify(formAdmin)
        })
        .then(handleError)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            res => {
                dispatch(postFormAdminSuccess(res));
            },
            err => {
                dispatch(postFormAdminError(err)); 
                console.log('erreur de response', err)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I'm using redux Thunk.

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import allReducers from './Reducers/Index';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';


const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore); 
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(
    allReducers
)


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I really appréciate if someone can help. I know it's working with a setTimeout fonction, but I'm sure that there is another way to do it.

Thank's for all ! 
hollowspy

Comment: Hi hollowspy, and welcome to StackOverflow! in React, `setState()` is asynchronous. In other words, when you call `setState()` the state doesn't actually update immediately. You're just _scheduling_ the state update, and React will apply it whenever it wants to. So the state of your component probably hasn't been updated by the time you call `this.onNaviguateAdmin()`. Try @Ujin's answer below and also see here for more info on updating state: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value

Comment: I knew that React is asynchronous. That's why I used the setTimeout fonction. That's why I would like to write a better code. I'll test @Ujin's answer and I'll say you ! Thanks :)

Comment: Yes i's working like @Ujin's solution ! Thanks both of you ! (and i'have vote to his answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass a callback to [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) so that `onNaviguateAdmin` is called after actual change to state:

```
this.setState({
    response,
    isSuccess
}, this.onNaviguateAdmin)
```

Note that `componentWillReceiveProps` is [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) and may be the cause of your problems. You should use `componentDidUpdate` instead:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    console.log(prevProps, this.props)
    if (this.props.Auth !== prevProps.Auth) {
        let response = this.props.Auth.response
        let isSuccess = this.props.Auth.isSuccess
        this.setState({
            response,
            isSuccess
        }, this.onNaviguateAdmin)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank's, it's works !! If componentWillReceiveProps is now deprecated, I suppose I should use componentDidUpdate. Is that correct ?

Comment: @hollowspy the new 'componentWillReceiveProps' is 'static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)'

Comment: @kivul `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not designed for performing side effects. And I guess that `onNaviguateAdmin` is meant to cause some side effects.